# How to reset a Leaderboard score for a tester account

Tags: oauth2-playground

I opened the Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Step 1:Select & authorize APIs
Input your own scopes i have filled htpps://www.googleapis.com/auth/games

and clicked button Authorize APIs.
Then i was prompted to choose account. I was confused to choose my Developer account or the tester account from which i want to reset Leaderboard scores.
I chose my developer account.

Step 2:Exchange authorization code for tokens
I have clicked button: Exchange authorization code for tokens

Step 3:Configure request to API.
In HTTP Method i have filled: POST

Request URI i have filled: https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1management/leaderboards/leaderboardId/scores/reset

with leaderboardId from my Google Play Console. 
I did not filled anything to (headers, enter request body). I left content-type: aplication/json
and Send the request

The response is

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Attempt to access application 834723478452 from application 407408718192.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Attempt to access application 834723478452 from application 407408718192.", 
        "reason": "ApplicationRequestNotAllowed"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Note that in Google APIs and Services i have enabled the management API for the specific project.

I repeated above steps for the tester Google account from which i want to reset Leaderboard scores but i got the same response.
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Finally i have been able to reset tester Leadeboards scores following instructions from   https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2015/05/10/android-how-to-reset-score-from-google-play-games-leaderboards/#.WdfjJVuCyHt